# RegQueryValueEx getting incorrect data

Tags: c++

I use this code to copy registry data from HKCU to HKLM. Between 1-9 the correct number is retrieved but on 10 I get a, 11 I get b, etc. I dont know what I have done incorrect, I wold be grateful for any help.

```
extern "C" UINT __stdcall ReadTempRegKey(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
UINT er = ERROR_SUCCESS;
HKEY hKey;
char szProductKey[MAX_PATH], lszValue[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR    achKey[MAX_KEY_LENGTH], achClass[MAX_PATH] = TEXT(""), achValue[MAX_VALUE_NAME];  
DWORD     cbName, cchClassName = MAX_PATH, cSubKeys=0, cbMaxSubKey, cchMaxClass, cValues, cchMaxValue, cbMaxValueData, cbSecurityDescriptor; 
FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;    
PHKEY phkResult = NULL;
DWORD i, retCode, cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME,dwType=REG_SZ,dwSKeyValueSize,dwSize=255;

hr = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "ReadTempRegKey");
ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to initialize");

WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Initialized.");  

Orc_Reg_Sub_LM_CU();

sprintf_s(szProductKey, "SOFTWARE\\%s",Orc_Get_Product_Name());

if( RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    szProductKey,
    0,
    KEY_READ,
    &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS
    )
{
    //Get the class name and the value count. 
    retCode = RegQueryInfoKey(
        hKey,                    // key handle 
        achClass,                // buffer for class name 
        &cchClassName,           // size of class string 
        NULL,                    // reserved 
        &cSubKeys,               // number of subkeys 
        &cbMaxSubKey,            // longest subkey size 
        &cchMaxClass,            // longest class string 
        &cValues,                // number of values for this key 
        &cchMaxValue,            // longest value name 
        &cbMaxValueData,         // longest value data 
        &cbSecurityDescriptor,   // security descriptor 
        &ftLastWriteTime);       // last write time 

    // Enumerate the subkeys, until RegEnumKeyEx fails.

    if (cSubKeys)
    {
        for (i=0; i<cSubKeys; i++) 
        { 
            cbName = MAX_KEY_LENGTH;
            retCode = RegEnumKeyEx(hKey, i,
                achKey, 
                &cbName, 
                NULL, 
                NULL, 
                NULL, 
                &ftLastWriteTime); 
        }
    } 

    //Enumerate the key values. 

    if (cValues) 
    {
        for (i=0, retCode=ERROR_SUCCESS; i<cValues; i++) 
        { 
            cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME; 
            achValue[0] = '\0'; 
            retCode = RegEnumValue(hKey, i, 
                achValue, 
                &cchValue, 
                NULL, 
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL);

            if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
            { 
                DWORD dwSize = sizeof(lszValue);

                retCode = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, achValue, NULL, &dwType,(LPBYTE)&lszValue, &dwSize);
```

`lszValue` is the data recieved.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to use my crystal ball to attempt to answer this.

The copying is being performed perfectly well, but you are viewing the data as hexadecimal rather than decimal. The decimal value `10` is `a` in hex, decimal `11` is `b` and so on.

Comment: Awesome, with closed eyes :-)

Comment: I'm new to C++ so sorry for the silly question, I had thought i was doing something wrong within my code. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question?